# How do I limit an output's maximum number of characters?

Tags: python, variables, int

I'm trying to limit a number's output to 4 characters (including decimals).

```
def costEdit(nCost):
    nCost = '%.2f'%(nCost*1.25)
    nCost = nCost * 1.25
    return nCost
```

I want the nCost to be cut off at 2 decimal places. E.g. if the nCost was 8.364912734, cut it off to 8.36 and edit the nCost variable to be replaced with that. Any Ideas?

Im getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\My Codes\TextTowns\TextTowns.py", line 59, in <module>
    costEdit(nCost)
  File "C:\Python33\My Codes\TextTowns\TextTowns.py", line 27, in costEdit
    nCost = nCost*1.25
  TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Im using it as: costEdit(nCost)

Comment: Terminology nitpick: if nCost equals `8.364912734`, it's not an integer. Integers are whole numbers.

Comment: Here is a side note. If you get a number bigger than 9.99, you'll run into 5+ characters. Is it more important to limit to 2 decimal places, or to only have 4 characters? Would you rather have `1000` than `1000.01`?

Comment: Do you want this function to return a string representation of a rounded number, or an actual rounded number?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of [python limiting floats to two decimal points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points). That question is about the fact that `13.95` has no exact representation as a `float`, and that Python 2.5 and earlier `repr`-d such values in an unintuitive way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is confusion between a number, and a string representation of a number. These are different things.

When you do this:

```
nCost = '%.2f'%(nCost*1.25)
```

… you're multiplying your number by 1.25, then replacing it with a string that represents the number up to two decimal points. So, when you do this:

```
    nCost = nCost * 1.25
```

… you're trying to multiply a string by 1.25, which makes no sense.

---

I suspect you didn't want a string here at all; you just wanted to round the number *as a number*. To do that, use the [`round`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function:

```
nCost = round(nCost*1.25, 2)
```

---

Of course as soon as you multiply by 1.25 again, you may "unround" it by another decimal place or two:

```
>>> nCost = 1.33333
>>> nCost = round(nCost*1.25, 2)
>>> nCost
1.33
>>> nCost = nCost * 1.25
>>> nCost
1.6625
```

And really, it's almost always a bad idea to round values before doing arithmetic on them; that just multiplies rounding errors unnecessarily. It's better to just keep the highest-precision value around as long as possible, and round at the last possible second—ideally by using `%.2f`/`{:.2f}` formatting in the printing/writing-to-disk/etc. stage.

---

Another thing to keep in mind is that not all real numbers can be represented exactly as floats. So, for example, `round(13.4999, 2)` is actually `13.949999999999999289457264`. A simple `repr` or `str` or `%f` will print this out as `13.95`, so you may not notice… but it's still not exactly 13.95.

The best way to solve this problem, and your other problems, is to use the [`Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) type instead of the `float` type. Then you can round the value to exactly 2 decimal places, do math in a 2-decimal-places context, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly, no flaws! *Gives KnightHood*

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be with the following:

```
def costEdit(nCost):
    nCost = '%.2f'%(nCost*1.25)
    #nCost = nCost*1.25
    return nCost
```

Let me break this down for you.

Take the line:

```
'%.2f'%(nCost*1.25)
```

And break it down into its components:

```
(' ( (%) .2f) ')%(nCost*1.25)
```

- Everything inside `''` is just a normal string.
- The `%` is a symbol that means "substitute in later".
- `.2f` is a command in Python that truncates 2 places after a decimal.
- `%(nCost*1.25)` means "`nCost*1.25` is what you put in place of `%`"

So in order, it does the math of `nCost*1.25`, puts it inside the string, then cuts off everything else and gives you what is left.

Take note that I've rewritten your `costEdit` function to accept `nCost` as an argument. This means that now you can call:

```
costEdit(nCost)
```

with any number that you want, and it will do the math.

Also note I've replaced `print` with `return`. This  means that now, you will have to write:

```
print costEdit(80)
```

to get

```
100
```

However it now means you can do math with `costEdit`, such as:

```
print 4*costEdit(80)
```

and instead of printing `100` along the way, it will just print

```
400
```

Questions? Leave a comment.

Happy coding!

EDIT: Regarding your error,

I think I've reproduced it and understand the problem.

When I type:

```
costEdit('15')
```

I get your error.

This is because when you do `costEdit('15')`, you're entering `'15'` and not `15`. If a value is between `''` or `""`, you're dealing with a value of *type* `string`.

In python, you can't multiply a `float` (type of number) with a `string`. That's what this is complaining about.

To remedy the situation, just remove the quotes. Then you're entering a number of type `float` or `int` (integer), both of which can be multiplied by a `float` (the value `1.25` inside `costEdit()`).

I hope this solves your issue-- I have to get off the PC for the night. If it doesn't help, leave a comment and I'll return tomorrow.

Otherwise, I'm glad I could help and remember to select a best answer on your question, so those who helped can get their *precious precious pointssssss*

Comment: Edit your original question-- add to the end. Plug in the block of code you're currently using to get this error, followed by this error itself. If I can't help you, someone else will.

Comment: It's fine when it's in this context. Can you go back and include what it is that you're inputting? As in the line: `costEdit(x)`?

Comment: @user3092506 Tried to fix your problem in my updated post. Give it a read. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.6 or higher, use format():

```
print('{0:.3g}'.format(nCost))
```

Comment: '{0:.2f}'.format(nCost) so 2f not 2g

Comment: Could you also talk about how to get this value as a numerical type? that would satisfy the "edit the nCost variable to be replaced with that" portion of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use special format code for floats

```
print('{0:.2f}'.format(nCost))
```

Change the 2f to 4f to increase the number of digits

Documentation(http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, any ideas? Code now:
`def costEdit():
    global nCost
    nCost = nCost * 1.25
    print('{0:.2g}'.format(nCost))`

Comment: use 2f not 2g. that should work. so '{0:.2f}' not '{0:.2g}'

Comment: This doesn't really do anything different from the `%.2f'%` in his existing code. And it doesn't solve his problem (trying to multiply the formatted string by 1.25, instead of multiplying the number and then formatting it).